# Behavior of "cross threaded operation not valid"

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, multithreading

I was trying to read in values from the GUI and I passed the data as shown below using `Task`. What I don't understand is it gives error because of only combobox field (that is `tab3_ddl_Range.SelectedText`) and if I remove it the error goes away. Shouldn't it still give the error? As I am accessing GUI from non GUI thread?

```
factoryA.StartNew(() => ReadInstrument_3(
    Globls.numReadings, tab3_txt_Address.Text.TrimEnd(), tab3_rb_DCI.Checked,
    tab2_rb_DCV.Checked, tab3_ddl_Range.SelectedText.TrimEnd(),
    tab3_rb_FixedZ_10G.Checked, tab3_rb_FixedZ_10M.Checked,
    tab3_rb_Azero_Off.Checked, tab3_rb_Azero_On.Checked,
    tab3_rb_Azero_Once.Checked, tab3_txt_Aper.Text.TrimEnd(),
    tab3_txt_Device_Timeout.Text.TrimEnd(), tab3_txt_SICL.Text.TrimEnd())
```

Comment: Assuming this is WinForms, can you modify the tags and /or title to say so?  For WPF, I'd normally say to use data binding to deal with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some properties of controls are cached and don't require a winapi call to retrieve their values.  In particular the Text property is stored in an internal string.  So reading the Text property in a thread doesn't raise an exception since that just returns the string value.  Writing however does, that requires updating that string *and* making a winapi call to update the native window.

It is the winapi call that triggers the exception.  In particular, accessing the Handle property.

Comment: hmm.So i guess then it's not valid for combobox to be read from a different thread as i tried the text property, which still raises the error. In what way i can read "tab3_ddl_range.SelectedText" without first storing the value in a string?

Comment: It is not valid to use *any* property of a control from a thread, except InvokeRequired.  The clear way ahead is to stop breaking the rules.

Comment: @Hans - more a curiosity, but happen to know if this behavior of 'can read from any thread' extends across WinForms (assuming that's the UI framework discussed here)?

Comment: @JamesManning - no, the OP already found a property where it doesn't work.  Most won't work.